# Why Java does not allocate memory as much as what we configure

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I'm using Java 8 on Centos 6. I set up to run my app with -Xmx4g -Xms4g and configure GC log.

```
[Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 98309K->0K(1223168K)] [ParOldGen: 212350K->302185K(2796544K)] 310659K->302185K(4019712K), [Metaspace: 35090K->35090K(1081344K)], 0.1157579 secs] [Times: user=0.36 sys=0.02, real=0.12 secs]
```

With above log, why Java does not allocate 4g for heap but only 4019712K
I'm just a little bit confused

Comment: 4019712K = 4019M = 4.019G
Hope that answers your question

Comment: Memory is usually measured in GiB = 1024^3 bytes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte

Comment: Thank @Peter. So 4g should be 4* 1024 * 1024 = 4931584K

Comment: 4 * 1024 * 1024 = 4194304. Which is never the less not the figure you have.  I have often found the usable space is a little less than the size you asked for, and I assume this is due to overhead of memory management.